# textarea issue with formatting text inside

Tags: html, css

i have this code here:

```
<label for='shenime'>Shenime nga Sherbimi per klientin:</label> <br/> <textarea name="shenime" id='shenime' cols=40 ><pre><?=htmlentities($row['shenime'])?></pre></textarea>
```

Now, inside the textarea, i don't get the text only, formatted according to `<pre>` style but i get something like:

```
<pre>Text here </pre>
```

I want to assign `overflow:visible` to the pre tag.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<textarea>` tag is an `input`, and as such doesn't recognise any HTML inside of the `<textarea>` and `</textarea>` tags as HTML. It's treated purely as text.

Simply put, what you're trying to do isn't possible because you can't have other HTML elements inside the `<textarea>`.